# ST_Dwithin Source Code

Tags: postgis, open-source-gis, postgis-2.0, algorithm

I am looking for the st_dwithin postgis source code. I want to learn the way postgis determines whether a given geometry is within a given radius to another geometry.

Comment: Google "postgis source download"

Comment: One place to start tracing could be http://svn.osgeo.org/postgis/trunk/postgis/lwgeom_functions_basic.c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best place to search and explore source code for PostGIS is through the GitHub mirror:

> https://github.com/postgis/postgis

For instance, search `ST_DWithin`, where you will then search `LWGEOM_dwithin`, then `lwgeom_mindistance2d_tolerance`, then `lw_dist2d_comp`, then `lw_dist2d_recursive`, and then different versions of `lw_dist2d_distribute*` functions ...

You can also explore the Doxygen documents for a high-level view of the liblwgeom library, which is part of PostGIS. E.g. for `measures.c`, which is used by `ST_DWithin`:

> http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/d1/dbf/measures_8c.html
>   [image: measures.c]

Here's how `lwgeom_mindistance2d_tolerance` connects with the other components:
[image: lwgeom_mindistance2d_tolerance]